# is-invalid class for a text box not works

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want the text box to be red color bordered when there is no value inside the text box  `<input type="tel" #phone="ngModel" [class.is-invalid]="phone.invalid" class="form-control" name="phone" [(ngModel)]="userModel.phone">`

Comment: use `!phone.valid` instead of `phone.invalid` like this:  `[ngClass]="{'is-invalid':  !phone.valid}"

Comment: is-invalid class will append when the form field is invalid. since you are not using any validation it will not work.

Comment: check stackblitz demo for your problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ekbuqz?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is use `"ngClass]="{'is-invalid': !phone.valid}"` and `required` attribute for input tag.

```
<input type="tel" #phone="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': !phone.valid}" class="form-control"  required name="phone" [(ngModel)]="userModel.phone">
```

Here is [Demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ekbuqz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

use `!phone.valid` instead of `phone.invalid` like this:

```
 [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': !phone.valid}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : phone.invalid}"`

AS:

```
<input type="tel" #phone="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : phone.invalid}" class="form-control" name="phone" [(ngModel)]="userModel.phone">
```

[More about ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Answer (score 0):

Your dash gets interpolated! Quotes are needed.
Something like this.

```
[ngClass]="{'is-invalid': someBooleanValue}"
```